# VS2008 XAML design view chokes on namespaced C++ assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, c++-cli

I have a C++ assembly with both managed and umanaged code compiled to
a DLL.  It is correctly imported into the project references as I can
see all my classes and their members with the Object Browser.

The problem is with the XAML Design view. In my XAML code I want to
make a data bind with my C++ assembly so I have the namespace like so:

```
xmlns:kudu="clr-namespace:kudu;assembly=CLI"
```

CLI is the name of the dll and it has a namespace inside called kudu.
The Design view refuses to shows the XAML and gives me this error:

```
Assembly 'CLI' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an 
assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced
assemblies have been built.
```

The best part is I can actually build the entire solution and
everything works! The window updates as the C++ objects change and
what not.  However with out the Design view this makes continuing
development quite difficult.

Does anyone have an answer as to why this happens and how I can fix
it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because the ide cannot load one of the unmanaged dll's. You may have to move them into the windows/system32.

Comment: I tried moving the other DLLs that this assembly needs to run to system32 but no such luck.  Still same problem loading error.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. I must have missed a file because I tried again with copying all our unmanaged DLLs to system32 and it works! 

THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution I've found to this is add to the windows PATH variable the bin directory of my assembly which has all the DLLs.

Comment: Don't forget to restart Visual Studio and watch the caveats mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036800/2439414) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful, thanks for this insight.

My solution is to copy the DLLs into the output directory using a Post-Build event.
Here's how
1.  Project Properties / Build Events 
2.  Set Post-build event command line:

copy path_to_dependent_dlls .

Oh, and I find that a VStudio restart is required for it to start working ...