# ViewModel does not exists in the namespace "clr-namespace:..."

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2013

I have a BIG and OLD xaml user control and I am trying to add ViewModel class for it (to do the things right).
 the code for attach viewmodel in xaml is:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Company.Proj.ViewModel;assembly=Company.Proj"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Company.Proj.View;assembly=Company.Proj"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type vm:SampleVM}">
            <v:MainWindow/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:SampleVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

and a class for future ViewModel:

```
namespace Company.Proj.ViewModel //the namespace is correct
{
    public class SampleVM    // the class is public
    {
        public SampleVM() // void constructor? perhaps not needed here
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting `SampleVM does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:Company.Proj.ViewModel;assembly=Company.Proj"`

I have googled a lot and found out many answers. like in
[The name ViewModel does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025601/the-name-viewmodel-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespaceproject-viewmo)

...I have tried to rebuildProjec/reopenStudio/change debug-release-debug/carefully)) copypaste assembly and namespece names...

But nothing solved ((
Is there any other variant to connect ViewModel to View.xaml(perhaps the better one that I have used) OR what coul be done to solve this issue ?

My VS version: VS Community 2013
 12.0.3.1101.00 Update 4 
Target Framework 4.5.1

EDIT: My question is different from above link because  In my question there is no mistake in clr-path (see top answer of Will)

Comment: Is the assembly correct?  If the `UserControl` is in the same assembly as the viewmodel, this shouldn't even be required.

Comment: Yes.. Buy the way assembly is not necessary here(one project) - I have also tried xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Company.Proj.ViewModel without assembly. The same error(

Comment: The problem is not finding SampleVM class, but the code is unable to find the namespace (or assembly) somehow.

Comment: Yes - the SampleVM is public class (take a look at my code) all this classes are from ONE assembly

Comment: possible duplicate of [The name ViewModel does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025601/the-name-viewmodel-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespaceproject-viewmo)

Comment: remove x:type, <DataTemplate DataType="vm:SampleVM">

Answer (score 0):

To debug it simply, you may try following steps:

1. Take a new project.
2. Add assembly Company.Proj.dll as a reference to it.
3. Try to map the viewmodel namespace (or any other namespace) with xmlns:prefix directive.

PS: As you asked in the question, void constructor is not a problem. It needs a constructor to get initialized. Classes without constructor cannot be initialized (except using factorymethods).

**Edit:**
You may like to see answers on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025601/the-name-viewmodel-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespaceproject-viewmo).

Comment: I have add reference, and xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Company.Proj.ViewModel;assembly=Company.Proj" - is marked as fine code(NO errors). But I could not see anything in usual dropdovn when I am typing <vm: ...  I have add this ref as Using to .cs file in this second project - all namespaces are visible and I have created a new() viewmodel class . But later, when I am compiling this  new proj - The type or namespace name 'Company' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Possibly .NET framework versions don't match. Check if your new proj and Company.Proj have same .net framework versions.

Comment: Yes)) your right - when I have corrected framework version I COULD create ViewModel class instance in .cs file (!And it compiles fine!) but COULDn't do it in xaml - still   no suggestions in drop down. -error vm:SampleVM was not found Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been build.

Comment: Did you look at the edit link I gave in the above answer. It has may solutions and descriptions given which are helpful.

Comment: yes, I have tried most of them yesterday. The problem is really very common.