# VisualStudios ERROR MainViewModel doesnt exist

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-sdk

Hy Guys i installed VS three times and everytime the same Error

I installed MVVM Light in the NUGET Manager for the MVVM
After installing i set the DataContext in the Main.Window on MainViewModel
That works now. But in my App.xaml is it not possible to get the Resource Dictonary in it. In attachment screenshots of my problem.

[appxaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVhB4.png) ( <= Full size image)

[image]

and...

[image]

Comment: Exactly in what namespace is ViewModelLocator defined?  Because I'll bet you 100$ it isn't defined in testapp.

Comment: I can't see if it's part of the MVVM Light framework, but if it is, your namespace is jacked.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025601/

Comment: You *reinstalled* Visual Studio 3 times to try and fix this?  Isn't that a little bit like buying a new car to try and fix getting lost on the freeway?

Comment: It is defined in the namespace testapp.ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare 'vm' namespace **before** usage, put it in Application tag.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Replace <vm: with <**local**: as the "local" namespace is aleady mapped at the root element in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="testapp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testapp.ViewModel"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Try xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testapp.ViewModel" as the ViewModelLocator is added to a "ViewModel" folder by default when you install MvvmLight using NuGet. I edited my answer.